# Javascript load content into div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a page that loads custom content into a div based on a click in an image map.

This is just some of the code, but the problem is that the content in the div with ID `piece` does not change when I click the link with ID `dec`.

I have tried normal links and many other techniques, but can't seem to get it working.

Appreciate all help!

```
  <map name="cake_01Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="249,246,250,25,130,46,249,246" href="#" alt="Desember" id="dec">
    <area shape="poly" coords="365,47,250,246,252,23" href="#" alt="Januar" id="jan">
    <area shape="poly" coords="448,134,252,251,368,49" href="#" alt="Februar" id="feb">
  </map>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col c4" id="piece">Content here</div>

<div>
    <img src="img/kake_01.png" alt="" width="500" height="500" usemap="#cake_01Map" id="cake_01" />
    <img src="img/kake_02.png" width="500" height="500" alt="" usemap="#cake_01Map" id="cake_02" />
</div>

</div>
</div>

<script>

$('#dec').click(function() {
  $('#piece').html('Content December');
});

$('#jan').click(function() {
  $('#piece').html('Content January');
});

$('#feb').click(function() {
  $('#piece').html('Content February');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `piece` id is unique -- which is correct. Try `$('#piece').text(whatever)`;

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: `piece` may be unique, but dec, jan, feb are not and the are used twice in the usemaps.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/tgdgLxkp/1/ Are you sure you've included jquery ? (*as that is what your code is using, and is it called after the dom is ready ?*)

Comment: I can' only see those ids once each. Am I missing some code?

Comment: They are there once each, but the map they are on is used twice.  This is not the issue ... I would be inclined to believe jQuery is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for all help, will look into comments when I get to my office. 

I was trying to make this work without jQuery. Since this will be put on an intranet and I don't know if they allow jQuery. 


Is that possible?


Best regards,
Reidar N.

Comment: I was hoping to fix it without jQuery, but ended up using it. Thanks for the help. See: https://konsulenten.no/trk/hjul.html